# Using general laws, prove that $\lnot(P\leftrightarrow Q)=P\leftrightarrow \lnot Q$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Prove that $\lnot(P\leftrightarrow Q)=P\leftrightarrow \lnot Q$, using general laws

I know it can be done by truth tables, but here the question is asked to be answered with general laws like (De Morgan, absorption, negation, double negation, distributive laws). Do you get it?

Comment: I tried a lot but i failed on the final steps , can someone explain it?

Comment: What do you mean by "using law"? What are you allowed to use? Truth tables will do here.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I know it can be done by truth tables , but here the question is asked to be answered with general laws like (De morgan , absorption , negation , double negation , distributive laws ) do u get it ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: @JessePFrancis , Yes I'm really new and it is my first time to ask an online question , thanks a lot and i will consider rewriting the post.

Comment: Intuitively they are both equivalent to $(P \land \lnot Q) \lor (\lnot P \land Q) $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition $P \rightarrow Q = (\lnot P \lor Q)$ and $P \leftrightarrow Q = (P \rightarrow Q) \land (Q \rightarrow P)$. Hence
\begin{align}
\lnot(P \leftrightarrow Q) &= \lnot ((\lnot P \lor Q) \land (\lnot Q \lor P))\\
&= \lnot ( (\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \lor (P \land Q))\\
&= (P \lor Q) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \qquad \mbox{de Morgan}\\
&= (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q) \land (Q \lor P) \qquad \mbox{Commutativity}\\
&= P \leftrightarrow \lnot Q
\end{align}

*Edit*
For the step between first to second line. By distributivity
\begin{align}
(\lnot P \lor Q) \land (\lnot Q \lor P) &= (\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \lor (\lnot P \land P) \lor (Q \land \lnot Q) \lor (Q \land P)
\end{align}

but $\lnot P \land P = 0, \lnot Q \land Q = 0$. Hence the second line.

Comment: Sorry but can u explain me How (¬P∨Q)∧(¬Q∨P)) became (¬P∧¬Q)∨(P∧Q))

Comment: @user283411 Edited.

Comment: I can't understand what have been done , please explain more How V Q became ∧ ¬Q

Comment: Which step are you referring to exactly? Line 1 to 2 is by [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), line 2 to 3 is by [de Morgan's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Thanks!

Comment: It's okay I didn't recognize that u edited it , I got it thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

For a change, I will propose a different approach:
If we assume:
$$\lnot(P\iff Q)\equiv P\iff \lnot Q$$
$$\implies\lnot(\lnot(P\iff Q))\equiv\lnot (P\iff \lnot Q)$$
$$\implies P\iff Q\equiv \lnot((P\implies \lnot Q)\land(\lnot Q\implies P))$$
$$\implies P\iff Q\equiv ((P\land Q)\lor(\lnot Q\land\lnot P))\equiv (P\land Q)\lor\lnot(P\lor Q)$$
But in detail if you want to entertain yourself experimenting (which is a good way to conclude in advance because your brain will accumulate more and faster):
$$(P\land Q)\lor(\lnot P\land\lnot Q)\equiv((P\land Q)\lor\lnot P)\land((P\land Q)\lor \lnot Q))$$
$$\equiv\underbrace{(P\lor \lnot P)}_{1}\land(\lnot P\lor Q)\land(P\lor \lnot Q)\land\underbrace{(Q\lor \lnot Q)}_{1}$$
$$\equiv(P\lor \lnot Q)\land(Q\lor\lnot P)\equiv\neg((\lnot P\land Q)\lor(\lnot Q\land P))\equiv\neg((P\land \lnot Q)\lor(Q\land\lnot P))\equiv\lnot(\lnot(P\iff Q))\equiv \underbrace{P\iff Q}_{again}$$
Hope it is fun!